Publishing dropcopy messages to Kafka using Quickfix/N, handling the case if Kafka is down
I implemented a dropcopy fix reader and processor using Quickfix/N with two .NET8.0 apps running on Ubuntu 22.04. First app opens up 8 TCP sessions to the market and reads dropcopy messages in parallel, writes all ExecutionReport and TradeCaptureReports as json to 8 kafka topics. second app reads kafka topics in 8 threads and writes to Postgresql db in batches. Provisioned UI will read from Postgres and show data in grid.
reader, processor apps, Kafka and postgresql run on the same server for now. UI will run on Windows clients. Unfortunately we don't have access to test environment and have to use production for now. As we are just reading information and not acting upon it thats fine for now. (we use some other tools for monitoring dropcopy but will be uninstalled soon.). As this software will become the single source of truth I'd like to handle cases that can cause message loss.

This is my configuration file:
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=2
FileStorePath=store
StartTime=06:00:00
EndTime=20:30:00
UseDataDictionary=Y
AppDataDictionary=FIX50SP2.xml
TransportDataDictionary=FIXT11.xml
SocketIgnoreProxy=Y
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
FileLogPath=log
ScreenLogShowIncoming=N
ScreenLogShowOutgoing=N
ScreenLogShowEvents=N
LogoutTimeout=5
ResetOnLogon=N
ResetOnLogout=N
ResetOnDisconnect=N
AllowUnknownMsgFields=Y
CheckLatency=N
SenderCompID=source_comp
TargetCompID=target_comp
HeartBtInt=30
BeginString=FIXT.1.1



[SESSION]
SessionQualifier=SESSION1
SocketConnectHost=….
SocketConnectPort=1234
Username=xxx
Password=xxx
SenderSubID=abcd

This is the code that reads dropcopy from market and publishes to Kafka:
public void OnMessage(QuickFix.FIX50SP2.ExecutionReport m, SessionID s)
{

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var account = m.IsSetAccount() ? m.Account.getValue() : null;

        if (account == "account1" || account == "account2")
        {
            var executionReport = ExecutionReportConverter.Convert(m, s);
            if (executionReport != null && executionReport.ExecType == 70)
            {
                var topic = s.SessionQualifier;

                await _kafkaProducer.PublishMessageAsync(topic, executionReport);
            }
        }
    });
}
public async Task PublishMessageAsync<T>(string topic, T message)
{
    try
    {
        string jsonMessage = JsonSerializer.Serialize(message);
        _logger.Information($"Serialized message for topic {topic}: {jsonMessage}");

        try
        {
            var kafkaMessage = new Message<Null, string> { Value = jsonMessage };
            var deliveryResult = await _producer.ProduceAsync(topic, kafkaMessage);

            _logger.Information($"Delivered message to {deliveryResult.TopicPartitionOffset}");
        }
        catch (ProduceException<Null, string> ex)
        {
            _logger.Error($"Error producing message to Kafka: {ex.Error.Reason}", ex);
        }
    }
    catch (JsonException ex)
    {
        _logger.Error($"Error serializing message: {ex.Message}", ex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error($"Unexpected error: {ex.Message}", ex);
    }
}


What if Kafka is down or the topics are not created yet when the app starts or goes down during the run? Does Quickfix/N have some internal buffering mechanism so I can publish when Kafka is up. Or can I check first Kafka status and then start reading(basically pausing Quickfix after logon)?

With regards to the code above. Can I filterout messages I am not interested in such as account numbers are not account1 or account2 before 'OnMessage' method is called?

When I start the app sometime after market starts it starts to read messages but some messages are not produced in Kafka even if its up(they are in Quickfix/n logs). In this case does quickfix/n reads messages faster then normal operation? Could the above code I use to produce is problematic such as messages overriding the previous ones?


I am debugging on the production machine and have limited testing means so thanks for you help.
